# What's wrong with this "time-updating function", in OpenOffice?

Tags: database, time, macros, openoffice-calc

I am using Calc (from OpenOffice) for my work.

---

I have a spreadsheet, like this:

[The first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMU4e.png)

If the **column F** is updated, the **column E** will be printed with the current editing-time.

I have written this macro for my work:

```
Option VBASupport 1
Global oListener As Object
Global oScalcDocument As Object
Global oGroup6 as Object
Global CurRow as integer
Global GnameCO as String
Global Gcheck_name as Boolean



Sub RangeEventlistenerOn

CurRow = 0

oScalcDocument=ThisComponent
'---installation of an event listenr
oListener = createUnoListener("OOO_","com.sun.star.chart.XChartDataChangeEventListener")
oSheet = oScalcDocument.Sheets(0)
oSheet.Protect("")
oGroup6=oSheet.getColumns.getByIndex(5)
oGroup6.addChartDataChangeEventListener(oListener)

End Sub


Sub RangeEventlistenerOff
oGroup6.removeChartDataChangeEventListener(oListener)
End Sub


Sub OOO_chartDataChanged
    CurRow = 2
'print(CurRow)
oScalcDocument=ThisComponent
oSheet = oScalcDocumet.Sheets(0)
'Get cell address
oSelection = oScalcDocument.getCurrentSelection
oRangeAddress = oSelection.getRangeAddress
CurRow = oRangeAddress.StartRow
oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(4,CurRow)
oCell.SetString(Format(Now,""DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss"))
End Sub


Sub Refresh()
Refresh_data (Format(Date, "DD.MM.YYYY"))
MsgBox("Work finished")
Exit Sub
Exit Sub
End Sub


Sub Save()
Save_data(Format(Date, "DD.MM.YYYY"))
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

---

Now, I want to change this spreadsheet to other-layout, like this:

[The second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE1i3.png)

If the **row 2** is updated, the **row 3** will be printed with the current editing-time.

So, I have changed this macro for my work:

```
Option VBASupport 1
Global oListener As Object
Global oScalcDocument As Object
Global oGroup6 as Object
Global CurCol as integer
Global GnameCO as String
Global Gcheck_name as Boolean



Sub RangeEventlistenerOn

CurCol = 0

oScalcDocument=ThisComponent
'---installation of an event listenr
oListener = createUnoListener("OOO_","com.sun.star.chart.XChartDataChangeEventListener")
oSheet = oScalcDocument.Sheets(0)
oSheet.Protect("")
oGroup6=oSheet.getRows.getByIndex(2)
oGroup6.addChartDataChangeEventListener(oListener)

End Sub


Sub RangeEventlistenerOff
oGroup6.removeChartDataChangeEventListener(oListener)
End Sub


Sub OOO_chartDataChanged
    CurCol = 2
'print(CurCol)
oScalcDocument=ThisComponent
oSheet = oScalcDocumet.Sheets(0)
'Get cell address
oSelection = oScalcDocument.getCurrentSelection
oRangeAddress = oSelection.getRangeAddress
CurCol = oRangeAddress.StartColumn
oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(3,CurCol)
oCell.SetString(Format(Now,""DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss"))
End Sub


Sub Refresh()
Refresh_data (Format(Date, "DD.MM.YYYY"))
MsgBox("Work finished")
Exit Sub
Exit Sub
End Sub


Sub Save()
Save_data(Format(Date, "DD.MM.YYYY"))
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

---

---

The updated code doesn't work correctly. Can you tell me: what's wrong in the change?

Comment: When you say "doesn't work correctly" - what, exactly, happens?  Describe anything it DOES do, including things you want to keep and things you want to stop, and please provide the full text and timing of any error messages that occur.

Comment: Also, to start I notice you add the listener on row 3 (index 2), when your post says you want the macro to activate based on changes in row 2 (index 1).  And you are printing the time to row 4 (index 3) when your post says you want to print to row 3 (index 2).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two types of problems.

> oGroup6=oSheet.getRows.getByIndex(2)

This gets the third row. As Lyrl explained, it should say index 1.  Change all of the indexes in the code to be 0-based (meaning 0,1,2,3), not 1-based (meaning 1,2,3,4).

> oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(3,CurCol)

The [getCellByPosition](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/table/XCellRange.html#getCellByPosition) method takes the column first, then the row.